# Apache poi HSSF returns incorrect no of physical rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on user given Excel file (.xls) and using Apache poi HSSF to read the worksheet. The Excel contains 16 rows physically.

- 13th row is empty.
- 14th row has data
- 15th row is empty
- 16th row has data

In this case,  `worksheet.getPhysicalRows()` returns 13.
While, `worksheet.getLastRowNum()` returns 16.

And note if I deleted 13th row, `getPhysicalRows()` returns 14.
if I also deleted 16th row, `getPhysicalRows()` still returns 14.

The last row with valid data is not read at all.

Have you encountered this behaviour with XLS?

Edit: I am not sure if this code can help the question.

```
 excelDocumentStream = new FileInputStream(new File(xlFilePath));
 POIFSFileSystem fsPOI = new POIFSFileSystem(new BufferedInputStream(excelDocumentStream));
 workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsPOI);
 int numOfRows = workSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
 int lastRow = workSheet.getLastRowNum();
```

Comment: Show the code how you're reading the data. I'd wager dollars to donuts that it's not POI that has a bug. You also say "The Excel contains 16 rows physically" which is wrong. Empty rows aren't physical rows.

Comment: Ok if "Empty rows aren't physical rows", POI should have returned 14 as the result ignoring the two physical rows.

Comment: Apache POI is simply telling you what Excel has written into the file. Your question sounds really to be more "why does Microsoft Office sometimes write unexpected values to an Excel file"....

Comment: Without seeing the Excel file and your code, it's impossible to determine what's happening. Nevertheless you can always read up to and including `getLastRowNum()` and ignore any empty rows you encounter.

Comment: As is this is a *yes I did* or *no I didn't* answer. What are you asking?

Comment: @Gagravarr, probably yes. If that is the case, I am looking for an anwser why POI returns two different answers in getPhysicalRows() and getLastRowNum().

Comment: @Gee Wasn't `getLastRowNum()` consistent and correct?

Comment: @Kayaman, yes, that work around is done.  Just wanted to know if someone had similar issues and what they found in XLS (if any) that caused this inconsistent result. I googled it and found nothing on this.

Comment: Well `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` just returns the size of the internal `TreeMap<Integer, HSSFRow>`. If you're claiming that it's returning less data than it should, then the sheet has been parsed wrong. Check what's happening with a debugger, and if it really is a bug, send the Excel to the POI people.

Comment: @Gee If you file was freshly created, and you'd only written to rows 1, 2 and 10, then there are 3 Physical Rows, but the last row is 10, so it's perfectly normal for the counts to differ!

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
int rows = 0;
if(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()>0)
   rows=sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;
```

Hope this helps!!!